# How to prevent C6284 when using CString::Format?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-warnings

The following code is generating warning [C6284](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta308ywy.aspx) when compiled with `/analyze` on MSVC 2008 : **object passed as parameter '%s' when string is required in call to function.**

```
 CString strTmp, str;
 str = L"aaa.txt"
 strTmp.Format (L"File: %s", str);
```

I'm looking for a nice solution for this that would not require `static_cast`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Microsoft describes the usage of CString with variable argument functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc%28VS.80%29.aspx#_core_using_cstring_objects_with_variable_argument_functions):

```
CString  kindOfFruit = "bananas";
int      howmany = 25;
printf_s( "You have %d %s\n", howmany, (LPCTSTR)kindOfFruit );
```

As an alternative you can also  use the method `PCXSTR CString::GetString() const;` to try to fix the warning:

```
CString strTmp, str;
str = L"aaa.txt"
strTmp.Format (L"File: %s", str.GetString());
```

Comment: Am I wrong or the correct solution is to use `str.GetBuffer()` ?

Comment: You could use both for your situation, but they have different meanings to the reader. `GetBuffer()`  returns a string buffer that allows for direct modification (not `const`) of the `CString` object whereas `GetString()` returns a `const` buffer for read only access.

Answer (score 5):

One of CString's design flaws, err, features is that it features an implicit conversion to `LPCTSTR` which makes the warning not that meaningful IMHO. But anyway, if you look at the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc.aspx), they actually use casts in their own example. I don't really see the need to avoid a `static_cast` here, in fact I would welcome it as it does make the implicit conversion more explicit and thus easier to spot.

Comment: I know this is old. But this answer has a wrong assumption: `Format` doesn't work because CString features an implicit conversion, but because CString's data layout is exactly the pointer to it's null terminated string, thus making it possible to use in wprintf style functions in MSVC. (see eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/4899199/321013)