# how does printf know the address of a CString's character data?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, printf, variadic-functions

Considering this code fragment:

```
struct My {
  operator const char*()const{ return "my"; }
} my;

CStringA s( "aha" );
printf("%s %s", s, my );


// another variadic function to get rid of comments about printf :)
void foo( int i, ... ) {
  va_list vars;
  va_start(vars, i);
  for( const char* p = va_arg(vars,const char*)
     ; p != NULL
     ; p=va_arg(vars,const char*) ) 
  {
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
  }
  va_end(vars);
}
foo( 1, s, my );
```

This snippet results in the 'intuitive' output "aha".  But I haven't got a clue how this can work:

- if the variadic-function call is translated into pushing the pointers of the arguments, printf will receive a `CStringA*` that is interpreted as a `const char*`
- if the variadic-function call is calling `operator (const char*)` on it, why wouldn't it do so for my own class?

Can someone explain this?

EDIT:  added a dummy variadic function that treats it's arguments as `const char*`s.  Behold - it even crashes when it reaches the `my` argument...

Comment: @David Heffeman: I know.  `printf` is my prototype variadic function.  The actual code I refer to is a `CString::Format`.

Comment: What platform is this? Visual Studio performs no conversion, it just pushes the entire value on stack. GCC issues an assert. I guess you are just "lucky" first member of CString is a pointer to the data.

Comment: @Suma: Wanna bet the first member of CString is a pointer to the data *on purpose*?

Comment: It may be on purpose, but hardly on purpose to allow passing into variadic functions, as that does not work anyway - you can pass one CString this way, but not two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant text of C++98 standard §5.2.2/7:

> The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the argument expression. After these conversions, if the argument does not have arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, pointer to member, or class type, the program is ill-formed. If the argument has a non-POD class type (clause 9), the behavior is undefined.

So **formally the behavior is undefined**.

However, a given compiler can provide any number of language extensions, and Visual C++ does. The [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z11y6be4.aspx) documents the behavior of Visual C++ as follows, with respect to passing arguments to `...`:

> - If the actual argument is of type float, it is promoted to type double prior to the function call.
> - Any signed or unsigned char, short, enumerated type, or bit field is converted to either a signed or an unsigned int using integral promotion.
> - Any argument of class type is passed by value as a data structure; the copy is created by binary copying instead of by invoking the class's copy constructor (if one exists).

This doesn’t mention anything about Visual C++ applying user defined conversions.

MS `CString` is "cleverly" layed out, so that it's POD representation is exactly the pointer to its null terminated character string. (`sizeof(CStringA) == sizeof(char*)`) When it is used in *any* printf-style function the function just get's passed the character pointer.

So this works because of the last point above and the way `CString` is layed out.

Answer (score 6):

What you're doing is undefined behaviour, and is either a non-standard extension provided by your compiler or works by sheer luck. I'm guessing that the CString stores the string data as the first element in the structure, and thus that reading from the `CString` as if it were a `char *` yields a valid null-terminated string.

Comment: He is not passing a `CString *` but a `CString`, which overloads `operator (LPCTSTR)`.

Comment: Quite right, I missed that. In that case, it's a non-standard extension.

Comment: why is it a non-standard extension?

Comment: If it's not defined by the C++ standard, then by definition it's a non-standard extension. My guess would be that the C++ standard didn't define it because variadic functions were seen as a holdover from C that were left in for backward-compatibility, and operator overloading (as in `std::cout`) was seen as a better way of doing the same thing. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Indeed: after careful looking-up, it seems that the first member of the `CSimpleStringT` template class is `PXSTR m_pszData`.  So reinterpreting a `CStringT` as `const char*` is, by sheer luck, okay.  Thanks!

Comment: Edited to be correct about the type being passed by value, not address.  This reinterpret-cast-like behavior, even though technically UB, would also require that sizeof(CStringA) == sizeof(char*), otherwise va_arg will apply an incorrect offset for further arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot insert Non-POD data into variadic functions.
[More info](http://tycho.ws/blog/2010/06/variadic)

Comment: You can, but it's undefined behavior.

Comment: You can pass My, but not CString. My is POD and is therefore passed with no coversion. The called function has no idea it is My and what it should do with it.

Comment: @sharptooth: "You cannot…" is commonly used for "It would be UB if you…", such as "you cannot index an array with an out-of-bound value".

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Yes, but people do something "you cannot do" and then complain that their compiler/runtime didn't emit an error.

Comment: @sharptooth: They deserve what they get.

Answer (score 1):

> if the variadic-function call is calling operator (const char*) on it, why wouldn't it do so for my own class?

Yes but you should explicitly cast it in your code: `printf("%s", (LPCSTR)s, ...);`.

Answer (score 1):

> If the variadic-function call is translated into pushing the pointers of the arguments, …

That is not how variadic functions work.  The *values* of the arguments, rather than pointers to the arguments, are passed, after special conversion rules for built-in types (such as char to int).

C++03 §5.2.2p7:

> When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the value of the argument by invoking va_arg (18.7). The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the argument expression. After these conversions, if the argument does not have arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, pointer to member, or class type, the program is ill-formed. If the argument has a non-POD class type (clause 9), the behavior is undefined. If the argument has integral or enumeration type that is subject to the integral promotions (4.5), or a floating point type that is subject to the floating point promotion (4.6), the value of the argument is converted to the promoted type before the call. These promotions are referred to as the default argument promotions.

In particular from the above:

> If the argument has a non-POD class type (clause 9), the behavior is undefined.

C++ punts to C for the definition of va_arg, and C99 TC3 §7.15.1.2p2 says:

> … if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases: [list of cases that don't apply here]

Thus, if you pass a class type, it must be POD, and the receiving function must apply the correct type, otherwise the behavior is undefined.  This means that in the worst case, it may work exactly as you expect.

Printf will not apply the correct type for any user-defined class type as it has no knowledge of them, so you cannot pass any UDT class type to printf.  Your foo does the same thing by using a char pointer instead of the correct class type.

Comment: "in the worst case, it works exactly as you expect"... I like that!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.  It doesn't even call the `operator const char*`.  Visual C++ just passes the class data to `printf` as if by `memcpy`.  It works because of the layout of the `CString` class: It only contains one member variable which is a pointer to the character data.

Answer (score 0):

Your printf statement is wrong:

```
printf("%s", s, my );
```

Should be:

```
printf("%s %s", s, my);
```

Which will print out "aha my".

CString has a converstion operator for `const char*` (its actually for `LPCTSTR` which is a `const TCHAR*` - `CStringA` has a conversion function for `LPCSTR`).

The `printf` call will not convert your `CStringA` object to a `CStringA*` pointer.  It essentially treats it like a `void*`.  In the case of CString, it is sheer luck (or perhaps design of Microsoft's developers taking advantage of something that isn't in the standard) that it will give you the NULL-terminated string.  If you were to use a `_bstr_t` instead (which has the size of the string first), despite having the conversion function, it would fail horribly.

It is good practice (and required in many cases) to explicitly cast your objects/pointers to what you want them to be when you call `printf` (or any variadic function for that matter).

Comment: He is explicitly using `CStringA` so he wants `(LPCSTR)`.

Comment: indeed.   I added the `my` later to illustrate the point.  I'll edit the question thuslike.

Comment: How will it "cast it to something that is useful"?  Where is that allowed?

Comment: `printf` will not cast.  It will `reinterpret_cast`.  It doesn't know the type of the argument, so cannot use the cast operator defined in `CStringT`.

Comment: @Fred:  You are correct.  I'll fix my wording, but the basic premise behind all this is that unless you specify what you want it passed as in the function call, it is undefined behavior.